# Validação de email

Tags: java, android

Como fazer que esse edittext seja valido apenas para um email? Que contenha por exemplo teste@gmail.com que contenha pelo menos o "@"?

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);


        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Cemail);


      btnfincad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mEmail = email.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar um método como o abaixo, se o que você está procurando é só validar o formato.

```
private boolean validateEmailFormat(final String email) {
   if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```